# How to reinstall OS X on an iMac which only has Ubuntu installed on it?

Tags: macos, imac, install

I have a 2011 iMac with only Ubuntu installed. It's not a dual-booted iMac, it only has Ubuntu installed.

How do I revert back to original OS X and remove Ubuntu? I've tried pressing various keys (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, etc.) to enter the boot menu,  but so far it hasn't worked.

Comment: If it is actually the Mid-2011 model it needs to have had a firmware update applied at some time in the past, or it won't be able to use Internet Recovery & you'll have to find a boot USB or CD for it. See https://support.apple.com/HT201314 & links. If it is capable, it should automatically switch to Internet recovery if it can't find a Recovery volume - that it isn't doing would indicate it doesn't have the firmware update.

Comment: The Apple site which lists which Mac need a firmware update is [Computers that can be upgraded to use OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313). Also, if your Mac has had Sierra or a newer version of macOS installed in the past, then the installation will probably have upgraded the firmware to allow Internet Recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out how to solve it : simply hold the alt (option) key since the booting, and it would lead to disk options.

Comment: This is not really helpful because there is a disconnect between your original question and the answer.  Do you have re-install media?  Do you have a recovery partition?  You should  provide this info.

Comment: Agreed, I have the problem as described where holding alt doesn’t work. I would assume there is some particular timing needed to make it work but that I simply get it wrong every single time.

Answer (score 3):

I have installed only Ubuntu. it warned that i may not be able to recover. However, if you hold Alt (option) key since the booting, it will prompt you to select a Wireless network (so make sure there's one available). Once connected it will ask you to confirm on Internet Recovery Mode. Select the option and proceed. This will take a while, so be patient.

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> key sequence at startup to boot from the Internet.

Use the Disk Utility application to reset Mac to a single `Mac Os Extended (Journaled)` partition. Make sure you are using a GUID Partition Table.

Quit Disk Utility application and choose to install OS X from the Menu bar.

Once OS X is installed, buy (for free) El Capitan (OS X 10.11) from the Apple Store. Download and install.

> Note: See [Startup key combinations for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) for more information.